# Is the Hamiltonian for the transverse field Ising model Hermitian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, linear-algebra, ising-model

I'm watching [these lectures](https://pirsa.org/C22002) in Condensed Matter Physics. At Lec. 13, the lecturer introduces the transverse field Ising model with the Hamiltonian
$$H = - J \sum_i \sigma_i^x \sigma_{i+1}^x - h \sum_i \sigma_i^z.$$
After looking at it for a while, it seems to me this is not a Hermitian Hamiltonian, because
$$(\sigma_i^x \sigma_{i+1}^x)^\dagger = \sigma_{i+1}^x \sigma_i^x,$$
and the latter term is not included in the sum. At first, I thought this was just a typo by the lecturer, but the same Hamiltonian is written in [arXiv: 2009.09208 [quant-ph]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.09208), Eq. (18), and in [this pdf from UBC](https://phas.ubc.ca/%7Eseme/516/smTutorial2.pdf), Eq. (4).

Is this Hamiltonian Hermitian? Shouldn't
$$H = - \frac{J}{2} \sum_i (\sigma_i^x \sigma_{i+1}^x + \sigma_{i+1}^x \sigma_i^x) - h \sum_i \sigma_i^z$$
be the correct form? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, I just noticed that spin operators in different sites commute, and hence the term $\sigma_{i+1}^x \sigma_i^x = \sigma_i^x \sigma_{i+1}^x$ is indeed in the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Yes, they commute by construction: $\sigma_i^x:=I\otimes I\otimes \cdots \otimes \sigma^x\otimes I\otimes \ldots$, where $\sigma^x$ is at the $i$-th position.